# Using regex to remove sub-string from a given field in a document and adding another sub-string in front of it in mongo

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

In a given mongo document given below if user want to remove "user" from "username" field and want to replace it with "Admin" so that all the users value changes to ["Admin1","Admin2"]

Old document:

> /* 1 */ {
> "_id" : "Alice",
> "name" : "Test1",
> "username" : "user1",
> "role" : "Admin",
> "password" : "04f8996da763b7a969b102" }
>
> /* 2 */ {
> "_id" : "John",
> "name" : "Test",
> "username" : "user2",
> "role" : "Admin",
> "password" : "8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd" }

Expected Document after update:

> /* 1 */ {
> "_id" : "Alice",
> "name" : "Test1",
> "username" : "Admin1",
> "role" : "Admin",
> "password" : "04f8996da763b7a969b102" }
>
> /* 2 */ {
> "_id" : "John",
> "name" : "Test",
> "username" : "Admin2",
> "role" : "Admin",
> "password" : "8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd" }

Answer (score 0):

db.getCollection('users').find({"role" : "Admin"}).forEach(function(doc) {
doc["username"] = doc["username"].replace(/.*user/, '');
db.getCollection('users').update({_id:doc._id}, {$set:{"username":"Admin" + doc["username"]}})
});